# Collections.replaceAll(List<T> list, T oldVal, T newVal) does not work with regex properly, Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm solving the problem where I must find the longest string in the list and replace all other list items with that string:

> **The longest string in the list**
>
> Inside the given method you should:
>
> ```
> 1. find the longest string in the list
> 2. replace all list items with the found string
> ```

When I use regular expression `"\\w+"` the method does not work:

`Collections.replaceAll(list, "\\w+", longestString);`

When I replace the specific words by specifying them in a method argument - all works properly, e.g.:

`Collections.replaceAll(list, "word", longestString);`

Why is that? Where is my error?

Comment: `Collections.replaceAll` does not work with regex.

Comment: Woudn't be simpler to use `Collections.fill(list, longestString)` instead?

Answer (score 1):

`Collections.replaceAll` method does not support Regex. Probably you should use `List.replaceAll` method:

```
list.replaceAll(e -> longestString);
```

---

Here is the working example:

```
// Dummy Values
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("Hey");
list.add("World");
list.add("Bye");
String longestString = "World";

// Replacing every word with `longestString`
list.replaceAll(e -> longestString);

// Printing
System.out.println(list);
```

**Output:**

```
[World, World, World]
```